# Globbing for a filename pattern with ls

Tags: linux, unix

I need help doing the following:

Say I'm in `/usr/bin` and I want to run the `ls` command on a subdirectory of `bin` called `datafiles` **from within** `bin`.

I need to locate all files using `ls` that contain a dot `.` and **contain the letters f or u anywhere after the dot**.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Side question: `/usrs/bin` or `/usr/sbin`? It looks like `/usr/bin` to me. In any case, this probably should be asked on another Stack..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ls datafiles/*.*[fu]*
```

Comment: Did I just help you cheat on your homework?